# Resizing textarea accoridng to jquery dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am new to css. I have a jquery dialog with a simple textarea in it, which pops on click of a button. After the dialog with textarea popsup, if I resize jquery dialog , I wanted textarea also to get resized relative to the dialog. How can I handle it ? Do we any css property for it to specify ? Below is the button click event code,

```
   function clickButton(){
      var dlg = $('<div style=width:500;> <textarea style=width:400> Sample text area       </textarea> </div>');
      dlg.dialog({
      width:600
     });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a percentage width on the textarea instead of a pixel width. The `90%` (chosen arbitrarily, make it whatever you need) below is relative to the `500px` size of the dialog, so if it gets resized, the textarea will scale with it.

```
var dlg = $('<div style="width:500px;"> <textarea style="width:90%;">Sample text area</textarea> </div>');
```

As good practice and to ensure valid HTML & CSS, please get in the habit of quoting your html attributes and explicitly specifying the `px` on a pixel size, as in:

```
<div style="width:500px;" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `% width` on the `textarea` and set its `box-sizing` to `border-box` to make the `borders` and `padding` included in the `width`.

```
<textarea style="width:100%; box-sizing:border-box;"></textarea>
```